# How to make a sprite jump inside update loop in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a ball sprite that falls from the top and a boy underneath it. When the ball hits the boy's head I want it to follow a parabolic path. I tried using CCJumpTo as follows but I cannot get it to work. I'm calling the action inside the update loop. Am I not allowed to do that? Cant I call CCJumpTo inside the update loop?

```
- (void) jump
{
if(!method_called)
{ 
    method_called=TRUE; 
    CCActionInterval *jump1 = [CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:3 position:CGPointMake(400, 400) height:150 jumps:1];
    [_ball runAction:jump1];
    NSLog(@"something");
}
else 
{ 
    NSLog(@"do nothing"); 
}
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
time ++;

if ( dpad.leftJoystick.velocity.x >  0 && x < 2000 ) {
    x = x + 10;
} else if ( dpad.leftJoystick.velocity.x < 0 && x > 0 ) {
    x = x - 10;
}
if (x > 10 && x < 2000)
    _boy.position = ccp(x, 100);


_ball.position = ccp(ball_x, ball_y);
ball_y = _ball.position.y - (speed * rebound);

_boy.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);    
CGRect boyBox = CGRectMake(_boy.position.x, _boy.position.y, [_boy boundingBox].size.width, [_boy boundingBox].size.height);
_ball.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
CGRect ballBox = CGRectMake(_ball.position.x, _ball.position.y, [_ball boundingBox].size.width, [_ball boundingBox].size.height);



if (CGRectIntersectsRect(boyBox, ballBox) && flag == 0)
{
    rebound = -rebound;

    flag = 1;
    topFlag = 0;
    [_ball stopAllActions];
    [self jump];

}
if (_ball.position.y > 700 && topFlag == 0)
{
    rebound = -rebound;
    flag = 0;
    topFlag = 1;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's my init method

```
-(id) init
{
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
if( (self=[super init]) ) {
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    self.ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" 
                                           rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    self.ball.position = ccp(275, 999);
    [self addChild:self.ball];  


    x = 0;
    ball_y = 650;
    ball_x = 300;
    rebound = 1;
    flag = 0;
    topFlag = 0;
    speed = 5;
    time = 0;
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
     @"boy.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"boy.png"];
    //spriteSheet.scaleX = 0.5;
    //spriteSheet.scaleY = 0.5;
    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"boy%d.png", i]]];

        CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:.1f];
        self.boy = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"boy1.png"];    
        _boy.position = ccp(100000, 100000);
        self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];
        [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
        [_boy runAction:_walkAction];
        _boy.flipX = YES;
        [spriteSheet addChild:_boy];

        dpad = [[MyJoystick alloc] init];
        [self addChild:dpad z:10];
        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
    }

    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

}
return self;
}
```

Comment: You can call CCJumpTo inside update loop. I tried out the same code. It seems to be working. Might be some other problem. You sure the the lines of code inside the condition check is executed?

Comment: Yes I did check. It is being executed. Till now I was bouncing it back by increasing _ball.position.y . That was working fine. But I wanted to bring about a parabolic path. That's why I tried the above. But nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Can you post the code of how you are making the ball move and adding the sprites. I tried out a simple moveTo on the ball and in the update the code you have posted and its working fine. So it has to be somewhere else.

Comment: While calling the update method, I passed the interval paramater as 0.1 and I could see the other animation. I think the time parameter for the parabolic animation is too high or something that I cant see the animation happening.I'll paste my init method also

Comment: On an unrelated note. There is a lot of unnecessary code inside the for loop. you are adding the sprite sheet and scheduling the update multiple times. You need the for loop only for adding the frames to the array.And with the co-ordinates of the ball and boy they would never meet. Post the code how the ball is moved.

Comment: As long as CCJumpTo is called only once the time parameter that you have passed to the update method doesn't matter since you are not manipulating the position of the ball anywhere else inside the update: method.

Comment: @Rakesh I've edited my post and included my update,jump and init method.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your action code inside a method and call it from update method using a boolean variable so that it would be called once only. Something like this:

take a boolean variable method_called in .h file:

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
    _boy.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0); 
    CGRect boyBox = CGRectMake(_boy.position.x, _boy.position.y, [_boy boundingBox].size.width, [_boy boundingBox].size.height);
    _ball.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
    CGRect ballBox = CGRectMake(_ball.position.x, _ball.position.y, [_ball boundingBox].size.width, [_ball boundingBox].size.height);

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(boyBox, ballBox) && flag == 0) 
    { 
        flag = 1; topFlag = 0; 
        [self callJumpAction];
    } 
}

-(void)callJumpAction 
{
    if(!method_called)
    { 
        method_called=true; 
        CCActionInterval *jump1 = [CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:3 position:CGPointMake(400, 400) height:150 jumps:1];
        [_ball runAction:jump1];
    }
    else 
    { 
        NSLog(@"do nothing"); 
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: tried using that method before.Implemented it again. Still nothing.
When I call update using
    [self schedule:@selector(update:) interval:0.1];
I can see the parabolic ball appearing faster than the ball going up

Comment: I finally got it to work without the help of the update method. That is what was causing the problem.